# Why isn't my Python package found when I attempt to install it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have tried installing the package invasion_PGF but constantly get the error messages:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement invasion_PGF (from versions: none)

and

> No matching distribution found for invasion_PGF.

I was installing using the command: `pip install invasion_PGF` in the Anaconda command prompt.

Can someone help me with ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Is this the library in question? https://github.com/joelmiller/Invasion_PGF

Comment: This package doesn't seem to be on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=invasion_pgf) where most pip packages are pulled from. You could get this from the GitHub link provided by isherwood.

Comment: Sorry about shredding your post. I hope I've clarified the problem and that it results in solutions. Welcome, and please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).